# snmp trap registering a receiver

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, mib, snmp4j

I'm new to `SNMP`. We have maybe 20000+ devices to listen `SNMP` traps. It is very hard to add to all `trap receivers`. Is there a way adding a `trap receiver`(destination) to a `trap sender` with `SNMP-set` `request` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on your devices.

One of the drawbacks (and advantages) of SNMP is that as an equipment vendor, you are in charge of what your device allows users to do over SNMP.

Each of the devices implements an SNMP Agent, which publishes a MIB, whose contents vary between makes and models. If a vendor decides to include a variable in their MIB where a manager (that's you) can set the trap destination, this will be easy for you. As long as you have a current list of the addresses and community strings of all your devices, it's easy enough to loop through the list with a shell script and do `snmpset`.

If the MIB doesn't include a trap destination variable, you're going to have to find another way.

If your 20k devices are heterogenous (ie they implement different MIB sets), they you have fun times ahead, figuring out which ones can be managed entirely over SNMP and which will require other access to set the trap destination.

So, start by gathering the MIBs implemented by your devices, and by reading them (try a MIB browser) you should be able to answer the question yourself.